# How to Upload a Photo from ASP.NET MVC to a WCF Web Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf

Hi I am trying to call a WCF web service from a default ASP.NET MVC project, in order to upload a photo to the server from the ASP.NET MVC website.
My WCF web service look like this:

```
public void SaveImage(string fileName, byte[] photo)
    {
        writeByteArrayToFile(Path.Combine(@"c:\TempImg", fileName), photo);
    }

    public void writeByteArrayToFile(string fileName, byte[] buffer)
    {
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {
            fs.Write(buffer, 0, (int)buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

In the HomeController on the project I have written this code:

```
using HackedTwo.ServiceReference1;

namespace HackedTwo.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ServiceReference1.IService1 myWS;

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                BinaryReader b = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
                byte[] binData = b.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);              

                myWS.SaveImage(fileName, binData);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe I am close to getting it to work? But when I run it I get a "NullReferenceException", in the top of the code where I declare the web service, there is a green line under "myWS" and I get this message from Visual Studio "Field 'HackedTwo.Controllers.HomeController.myWS' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null". So somehow I suspect that that might be the problem why this is not working. If that is so then my question is now: **How to assign the field 'HackedTwo.Controllers.HomeController.myWS'? Or should I reference the web service in some other way into my ASP.NET MVC project?**

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize this `myWS` variable before using it:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            using (var myWs = new ServiceReference1.MyServiceClient())
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
            {
                var binData = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);              
                myWS.SaveImage(fileName, binData);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

or if you are using dependency injection:

```
[HandleError]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService1 _myWs;
    public HomeController(IService1 myWs)
    {
        _myWs = myWs;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";

        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
            {
                var binData = reader.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);              
                myWS.SaveImage(fileName, binData);
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

and then you need to configure your dependency injection to pass the proper implementation of the `IService1` service contract interface in the controller constructor.

Comment: I then try to write in my code: using (var myWS = ServiceReference1.IService1) 
                { 
                    myWS.SaveImage(fileName, binData); 
                } But I get red lines both under "using" - "HackedTwo.ServiceRerence1.IService1': type used in using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDispoable'", I also get red lines under the service reference: "HackedTwo.ServiceRererence1.IService1' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @rune007, that's not what I showed in my answer. `IService1` is an interface. You cannot instantiate it. You should use the class that derives from it. Normally this class was generated when you imported the WSDL. The correct way is: `using (var myWs = new ServiceReference1.SomeServiceClient())` where `SomeServiceClient` is the class implementing `IService1`. I've also missed a `new` in my answer, sorry about that. I've fixed it.

Comment: I tried to run your first answer. Just in the top of the HomeController class I put the line: private ServiceReference1.Service1Client myWS; Still there was a green line under myWS and still when I tried to run the code I got the same NullReferenceException. I guess right now my problem simply amounts to: How to consume a default WCF web service in a default ASP.NET MVC project? I am pretty sure that I know how to add the service reference to the project correct, so that basic point I think is ok.

Comment: I found out how to reference the web service, it was as simple as this: using (ServiceReference1.Service1Client myWs = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client()) Still I can't get the system to work, when I run the projects I get this error "ProtocolException was unhandled by user code - The remote server returned an unexpected response:(400) Bad Request. "
I suspect the problem with the solution is that the code we have put together in the Action Method is not correct for calling my particular web service. But I can't figure out how to make it work. Any ideas?

Comment: I found out that I needed to set the maxReceivedMessageSize to something larger in the Web.config file of the Web Service. I pasted the code below into the Web.config and, Hey! Then it worked:  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="1000000000" />
     </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>